# Could not find a part of the path.Copy a file from an application. WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, image, copy

I have a folder in my WPF application - Helpers/1.png. This folder contains images and xml files. When I run my program from Visual Studio it works okay. However, when I run "exe" file of my program from another logical disk, I've seen such an error:

```
Could not find a part of the path ""..//..//Helpers//1.png"
```

I would like the image("1.png") and xml filee to be copied from the executable application where the application is run and copied by an user.

[image]

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify what happens with a file in your project via the properties of the file:

[image]

`Build Action` to `Resource` and `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy always` will mean that the file is copied to the output directory of the solution as a file (i.e. you can see it in Explorer).

If you use the file in your application, it must be present on the disk at the specified absolute or relative path. Otherwise you will get the error you describe. If I understand you correctly, you want to create a self contained executable, which runs no matter where it is copied. This means that your application cannot depend on any external files.

To solve this, you need to embed all external files into the executable and change your code to work with these embedded files rather than to expect files on the disk.

Here is a method to get you started:

```
public static byte[] GetResourceAsByteArray(string filename)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        using (var resFilestream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filename))
        {
            if (resFilestream == null) return null;
            var ba = new byte[resFilestream.Length];
            resFilestream.Read(ba, 0, ba.Length);
            return ba;
        }
    }
```

To use it, you need to set the build action of your file to `Embedded Resource`, and call the method with the fully qualified name of the file, where the name is assembled like this:

`[RootNameSpaceOfTheProject].[NameOfFolderInTheProject].[FileNameWithExtension]`

Example:

[image]

Call the method:

```
var b = ResourceOperations.GetResourceAsByteArray("Store.Resources.EmbeddedIcons.toolbox.png");
```

Now you can write the byte array to a temporary file for example and use this as an image source, or you can build an image from the byte array directly. At least, you've got your data...

Answer (score 2):

What does the folder structure look like when run from another logical disk?  Are you sure the files are present?  Are they actually located two folders down from the location of the executable?

For example, if this is your executable:

```
x:\path\to\your\executable.exe
```

Is 1.png actually located here? :

```
x:\path\Helpers\1.png
```

If the files are absent, check the properties of the *.png files in your solution to insure the Build Action of each is set to copy the files to the output during build.

Updated:

You cannot use the "....\" path for specifying the location of 1.png.  What you are doing is telling the executable to use 1.png from the VS project.  When you build, your program is output to the relative path bin($Configuration) (bin\Debug or bin\Release).  So when you execute a debug session, your application is going down two directory levels to the VS project files and grabbing 1.png.  However, the VS project is not present in your deployed application.

You need to do two things:

```
1) Change your program code to load "Helpers\1.png" instead of "..\..\Helpers\1.png"

2) Highlight 1.png in VS Solution Explorer, right click, and select Properties.  In the    Properties pane change 'Build Action' to 'Copy Always' or 'Copy if Newer'.  (Another response here provided an excellent guide with screenshots)
```

This way your build process will create the relative path 'Helpers' and copy 1.png to it.  Thus insuring that no matter where you deploy your app, the path and file will exist.

**To demonstrate the difference, before making these changes, navigate to the folder containing your VS project and then go to the path bin\Debug.  You will see Helpers\1.png does not exist here.  Make the two changes I outlined above, rebuild, and then have another look at bin\Debug.  you will now see bin\Debug\Helpers\1.png exists.**

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the File or Image any thing and then click on Properties.
Then Select the Build Action Content,Copy to output Directory As Copy Always.

If your are building the Setup using Install Sheild

Select the Content Files Check box while adding the project out put file.

you need do the coding based on the settings.

First you have declare three strings.

```
    private string strCurrentFolder = "\\give the Project path\\bin\\Debug";
    private string strXMLFolder = "\\give the project folder path\\give folder name where the files stored";
    but the folder sholud be there in Project.

    private string strXMLSetupFolder = "\\give folder name where the files stored";
    string XMLFilepath;

     if (Application.StartupPath.Contains("Project Name"))
           XMLFilePath = Application.StartupPath.Replace(strCurrentFolder, strXMLFolder);
    --This is for Visual Studio run

    else
          XMLFilePath = Application.StartupPath + strXMLSetupFolder;

    --this is for insatllation folder path
```

finally you will get the folder path from XMLfilepath string.

XMLFilepath\give the file name ;

Answer (score 0):

When you debug your program in VS it is run with a different "working directory". This means that GetCurrentDirectory might not return the directory the program is actually located in. 
Set the build action as described in the other answers, then use this code to get the file's path:

```
string epath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; // this is the full path to the program
string filepath = epath.Substring(0, epath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "Helpers\\1.png"; // this is the full path to the file you need
```